# Angular 2 Reactive Forms cannot find control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Im new with Reactive Forms and Im trying to make a component that has `indicadores` with `answers`:

With this component:

```
addAnswers(indicador: Indicador, answer?: any):void {
    const indicadoresFormArray = <FormArray>this.customForm.controls['indicadores'];

    let label = answer ? answer.label : '';
    let value = answer ? answer.value : '';

    let superi = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < indicadoresFormArray.length; i++) {
        if(indicadoresFormArray.value[i].id == indicador.id) {
            superi = i;
        }
    }

    (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>(indicadoresFormArray).controls[superi])
    .controls['answers']).push(
        new FormGroup({
            label: new FormControl(label),
            value: new FormControl(value)
        })
    )
}
```

And the template

```
<div *ngFor="let indicador of customForm.controls['indicadores'].controls">
<div class="row" *ngFor="let answer of indicador.controls['answers'].controls">
    <div class="input-field col m5 s6"><input formControlName="label" placeholder="Etiqueta" /></div>
    <div class="input-field col m5 s6"><input formControlName="value" placeholder="Valores" /></div>
    <div class="input-field col m2 s12 center-align">
        <button type="button" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light" (click)="addAnswer()"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It's always throwing the exception:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'label'
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'value'
```

And I dont have any idea why...

**console.log(indicadoresFormArray);**
[image]

Comment: public customForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.customForm = this.fb.group({
      label : [null],
      value : ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
Try this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was some issues with your template, missing a few `formArrayName`'s and `formGroupName`'s.

Each `FormArray` needs to have marked in template `formArrayName="the name of the array"` and if you are having nested `FormGroup`'s inside the array they need to be marked in this case with the index (which you get from the iteration of the `FormArray`), like so: `[formGroupName]="i"` or `formGroupName="{{i}}"`.

So your template should look like the following:

```html
<!-- Mark formarray before iteration -->
<div formArrayName="indicadores">
  <!-- Mark formGroupName in a div inside iteration or on the same line -->
  <div *ngFor="let ctrl of customForm.get('indicadores').controls; let i = index" formGroupName="{{i}}">
    <label>Predefined</label>
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="predefined">
    <!-- Again mark the formarray.... and formgroupname below that -->
    <div formArrayName="answers">
      <div *ngFor="let cont of ctrl.controls.answers.controls; let j=index" formGroupName={{j}}>
        <input formControlName="label" placeholder="Etiqueta" />
        <input formControlName="value" placeholder="Valores" />        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/3HfnxqJwYa49T0u6N18j?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, im getting the error: `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: '0 -> label'`

Comment: Could you provide a working plunker to showcase the issue and I'd be happy to take a look at it. Much easier to help when you have something to test :)

Comment: I was trying to make a plnkr but is not working, this is actually my work: http://plnkr.co/edit/w7wJNRKmwwLkkN3AgUy3?p=preview following your instructions of my previous answer

Comment: Well it's not working as you said, you are at least `initForm` function in the plunker :)

Comment: Its working! thank you so much @AJT_82 I started thinking that I had lost all week doing this. Just 2 questions: With the same expamle, I am able to print an `Indicador.name`? I tried with `<h5>{{ ctrl.IndicadorNombre }}</h5>` but is not working so actually Im printing It with `<input type="text" formControlName="IndicadorNombre" readonly>`. And last one, with the `formControlName="predefined"` switch I wanted to make an `*ngIf="predefined"` to show one or other div, how is possible?

Comment: Seems all plunkers is not working for me, so I cannot fork my plunker to show you. But you should be able to do the following inside the iteration of `indicadores`: `<h5>{{ctrl.value.IndicadorNombre}}</h5>`  and the div:`<div *ngIf="ctrl.value.predefined">It's true!</div>`

Comment: Done! all works right! Yeah, today plnkr is working a bit weird but you solved all my questions thanks :)